Are Lagrange multipliers applicable to Nesbitt's inequality?
See linked
Nesbitt's inequality, after normalization, is equivalent with
$$\frac{a}{1-a}+\frac{b}{1-b}+\frac{c}{1-c}\ge \frac{3}{2},$$
with $a, b, c$ positive and $a + b + c = 1$. What troubles me is when we try to apply Lagrange multipliers, the set $(0, 1)^3$ is not closed, so we cannot guarantee that a minimum value even exists. It would be nice to prove the inequality for all $(a, b, c) \in [0,1]^3$, as this set is closed and bounded, and hence has a minimum. The issue arises when one of $a, b, c$, say $a$, is $1$, as the term $\frac{a}{1-a}$ then blows up to infinity.
Is there a clever way to overcome this issue, or are Lagrange multipliers not applicable here? Perhaps I misunderstand them.

If any of $a, b, c$ is $\ge 3/5$ then the inequality holds. Therefore it suffices to prove it for $(a, b, c) \in [0, 3/5]^3$.

Typo:  presumably the last summand should be $\frac c{1-c}$.  Note too that there is no problem with $\frac a{1-a}$ when $a=0$....the problem comes when $a=1$ but that's not allowed.  And, of course, if any of the terms are near $1$, the inequality is clearly satisfied.

@lulu yes sorry. Both of those are typos. I will correct them

I am not sure whether the Lagrange Multipliers is applicable. But the inequality (for those $(a,b,c)\in (0,1)^3)$  can be solved by adding $3$ and using $A.M.\ge G.M.$ twice as below.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{a}{1-a}+\frac{b}{1-b}+\frac{c}{1-c}+3 
= & \frac{1}{1-a}+\frac{1}{1-b}+\frac{1}{1-c} \\
\geqslant & 3 \frac 1{\sqrt[3]{(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)}} \\
\geqslant & 3\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1-a+1-b+1-c}{3}}\right) \\
= & \frac{9}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Removing $3$ yields
$$
\frac{a}{1-a}+\frac{b}{1-b}+\frac{c}{1-c} \geqslant \frac{3}{2}
$$
